# Warhammer rpg High level campaign

Tags: game-recommendation, warhammer-40k

So I am thinking about running a RPG style campaign set in 40k however, the story planed doesn't fit into the RPG's I have seen like Dark heresy and the base system nor can I find any d20 systems that would support a Primarch campaign reflavoring to fit the 40k setting. what would the best system to run a Primarch player character campaign

Comment: Welcome to the stack! I recommend checking out the [tour] to understand better how this site works. Any additional question may be answered in the [help], or asked in comments here. You may also ask them in our [chat].

Comment: As I understand it, this question seems like a system shopping question, [which is off-topic here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might have better luck on another site. Here's a [curated list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/77044) of other forums where you may ask this kind of question.

Comment: I'll not answer because we do not do shopping answers here, but are you aware that there is a [Role-Playing Game for Warhammer 40K](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse.php?filters=0_2140_44242_44499_0) from the creators of Warhammer? Not everything has to be a d20 game. Or use a level-based system.

Comment: *cough cough cough*, your players are going to play PRIMARCHS?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin 40k is **a whole huge slew of games.** There's [Deathwatch, Only War, Rogue Trader, Black Crusade, Dark Heresy, Dark Heresy 2.0](https://www.40krpgtools.com/library/), [Wrath & Glory](https://cubicle7games.com/our-games/wrath-glory), ... Oh, and then there's good old [Inquisitor](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Inquisitor_(Game)) that can be played as *quasi-RPG*... in fact... the listed ones got about 4 or such underlying systems - all but Wrath & Glory started as FFG games, and DH2.0 is a significant change and Inquisitor was its own special spiel...

Comment: Primarchs are so ridiculous that I wouldn't try to run them in any of those systems. I don't think even Deathwatch would do the job. (I have ideas about what systems I *might* use, but shopping question.